# How to call a lua script which uses Torch7 packages from c++?

Tags: c++, lua, cmake, torch

I have a c++ source code called DeepQ.cpp from which I am trying to call certain functions within a lua script DeepQLearner.lua. This lua script uses Torch7 packages. I know how to call a simple Lua script from C++ but there doesn't seem to be much resources around for learning how to include the Torch stuff within it. My scripts DeepQ.cpp and DeepQLearner.lua are as follows:

DeepQ.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>

extern "C" {
    #include "lua.h"
    #include "lualib.h"
    #include "lauxlib.h"
}

using namespace std;
lua_State* L;
int main (int argc, char** argv)
{  
  L = lua_open();

  //load Lua base libraries 
  luaL_openlibs(L);

  // initialize Lua 
  luaL_dofile(L, "/home/sp/DeepL/DeepQLearner.lua");

  lua_getglobal(L, "initialize");
  lua_call(L, 0, 1);

  return(0)
}
```

DeepQLearner.lua

```
require 'cutorch'
require 'cunn'
require 'image

function initialize()
  -- some code here
end
```

This is my CMakeLists.txt which works fine for invoking lua scripts as long as no Torch modules are used:

```
cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 2.4.6)
project (DeepL)

set(EXECUTABLE_OUTPUT_PATH ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/bin)
set(CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE RelWithDebInfo)

find_package(Lua51 REQUIRED)

include_directories (
    ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}
    ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}
    ${LUA_INCLUDE_DIR}
)

add_executable (${PROJECT_NAME} src/DeepQ.cpp)
target_link_libraries (${PROJECT_NAME} lua5.1)
```

I think this does not work in case of Torch because Torch by default uses LuaJIT. In CMakeLists.txt I tried doing `find_package(LuaJIT REQUIRED)` but with no success. How to modify the CMakeLists.txt so that the lua code is executed with LuaJIT instead of Lua5.1 and the Torch packages are correctly found, and what other header files need to be included in the .cpp file? Thanks in advance.